# Programmatically trigger React-Select to select/commit the top option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

We're using React-Select as a controlled component and we need to allow a user to press `Enter` in another field and have it trigger our React-Select component to select and commit the top option in the list.

Controlling whether the menu is open or not is simple with the `menuIsOpen` prop, but it seems like catering to using the component in a controlled way stops there.

Controlling the selection/committing of options is proving quite difficult. We have a ref assigned to the React-Select instance but I can't find any way to trigger it to select the top option. Any ideas?

I've just started reading through the source code and will update this with any good clues I find.

Comment: Wouldn't the currently-selected option be driven by a state value and you'd just update that state value?

Comment: @David how do we _commit_ that value though? How do we get it to trigger the normal sequence that would commit the selection, including having it call its `onCreateOption` prop if relevant?

Comment: Perhaps if you could put together a runnable example demonstrating the problem, either in a code snippet here or on something like CodeSandbox?